# php bin setup upgrade error

Tags: magento2.3

I'm receiving errors after disabling custom extensions I wasn't using (I deleted their folders first by mistake).

Then after disabling modules from `php/bin` command these errors are occuring site-wide

```
        1 exception(s):
    Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid Document 
    Element 'route': Duplicate key-sequence ['checkout'] in unique identity-constraint 'uniqueRouteFrontName'.
    Line: 4


    Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid Document 
    Element 'route': Duplicate key-sequence ['checkout'] in unique identity-constraint 'uniqueRouteFrontN

ame'.
Line: 4
```

What did I do to fix this ? It's happening even if I do `php/bin setup:upgrade` same error everywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `app/etc/config.php` and remove the module names of your custom module that you just delete or want to delete it...

Go to mysql, remove your module from `setup_module` table, `delete from setup_module where module = 'Vendor_Module'`...

Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`...

If your Custom Module folder exist in `app/code`, remove it.

Comment: than you very much it is working!